# dividing values in spinners - Android

Tags: java, android, spinner

I am trying to get the values from spinner 1 and divide it with the value from spinner 2 and then multiply with the current amount. This is the code i have but it gives me a force close when i try and convert.

```
final EditText editCurr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etamount);
    Button convert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_convert);
     convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v){
             double curr = Double.valueOf(editCurr.getText().toString());


                double result2 = Double.valueOf(spinner1.toString()) / Double.valueOf(spinner2.toString());
                double result = curr * result2;
                etResult.setText(String.valueOf(result));
         }
     });
```

to make it more clearer what i'm trying to do i have shown the xml of my array:

```
<string-array name="currencies">
    <item>EUR, Euro</item>
    <item>GBP, British Pound</item>
    <item>USD, US Dollar</item>
    </string-array>

<string-array name="currenciesvalues">
    <item>1</item>
 <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
</string-array>
```

currencies are the string that show on the spinners and currenciesvalues are numbers assigned to the string e.g EUR has a value of 1.
in the method im trying to get the amount from curr and multiply by the value that occurs from dividing the value of spinner1 with spinner2 e.g. USD value 3 / GBP value 2

hope this makes it a little clearer

Comment: Can you show the logcat

Comment: im not sure what i need to show. Should i copy the whole thing because there is a lot

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting the value of the `Spinner` and assigning it to `spinner1` and `spinner2` somewhere in the code that you have not posted?

If you are not then that is where the problem is. You can't get the `Spinner`'s value by just calling `spinner1.toString()` or `spinner2.toString()`.

To get the value of the `spinner` use...

```
spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

So in your case...

```
double result2 = Double.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString()) / Double.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the bug:

```
double result2 = Double.valueOf(spinner1.toString()) / Double.valueOf(spinner2.toString());
```

Change it to:

```
double result2 = Double.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString()) / Double.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

Comment: i tried this but still force closes. Thanks for the suggestion