# dividing two spinner values

Tags: java, android, spinner

i have managed to get the spinner values to show on the textbox but i need to divide the values with each other. so i have to divide the value of spinner 1 with the value of spinner 2. however i am unsure how to do this.

here is my code:

```
public class CurrencyActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.currency);


 final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
 final Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
 final EditText etResult = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etResult);
 final MyData items[] = new MyData[3];
 items[0] = new MyData("EUR, Euro","1.00");
 items[1] = new MyData("GBP, British Pound","5.00");
 items[2] = new MyData("USD, US Dollar","15.00");

ArrayAdapter<MyData> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <MyData>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){
        MyData d = items[pos];
        etResult.setText(d.getValue());
}

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent){
        //Do nothing

}
});



spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){
        MyData d = items[pos];
        etResult.setText(d.getValue());
        }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent){
        //Do nothing
    }
 });
```

i created a MyData class which has these methods

```
public class MyData {

    public MyData(String spinnerText, String value){
        this.spinnerText = spinnerText;
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getSpinnerText(){
        return spinnerText;
    }
    public String getValue(){
        return value;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return spinnerText;
    }
    String spinnerText;
    String value;

}
```

thank you

Comment: Related to your previous questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871238/dividing-values-in-spinners-android and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18045703/dividing-values-in-2-spinners?

Comment: @Raghunandan yes but ive made a little bit more progress. The other solution did not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to solve the problem.

I changed the type of value in the MyData class from String to double.
I created two double fields in the CurrencyActivity called valA and valB.

then in the method i assigned the value of the spinner to the val field e.g.
valA= d.getValue();

I then created a new method and just did valA/valB;

here is the code to help make it easier to understand.

```
public class CurrencyActivity extends Activity {
double valA; 
double valB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.currency);


final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    final Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    final EditText etResult = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etResult);
    final MyData items[] = new MyData[3];
    items[0] = new MyData("EUR, Euro",1);
    items[1] = new MyData("GBP, British Pound",5);
    items[2] = new MyData("USD, US Dollar",15);

ArrayAdapter<MyData> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <MyData>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){
        MyData d = items[pos];
        valA=d.getValue();
}

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent){
        //Do nothing

}
});



spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){
        MyData d = items[pos];
        valB = d.getValue();
        }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent){
        //Do nothing
    }
 });

public void divideVals(){

    double result = valA / valB;
    etResult.setText(String.valueOf(result));
}
```

Hope this helps others as it took me ages to work it out which was very simple in the end.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution but I think you are mixing code up here.
`Integer.parseInt(d.getValue())` will give you a valid `int` that you can perform any math function on but in your code you literally overwrite `MyData d` when each Spinner selection is changed.

You could add another field to your `MyData` class that will store whatever value you want as an `int` and then simply use `mydata.getVal()` assuming `mydata` is of type/class `MyData`.

Comment: Thank you, your solution helped me in the right direction. I created two more double fields in the CurrencyActivity e.g. valA and  valB and then valA = d.getValue() i then created a method and just did valA / valB;